# rails bundle install error therubyracer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i tried installing the gem separately and v8 file also. I'm lost on what to do as I've exhausted all possible options

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/giowong/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
checking for main() in -lobjc... yes
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

 Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/giowong/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/bin/ruby
--with-pthreadlib
--without-pthreadlib
--with-objclib
--without-objclib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
--with-v8-dir
--without-v8-dir
--with-v8-include
--without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
--with-v8-lib
--without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
/Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in `configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of   
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

from     /Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in   /Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to   /Users/giowong/rails_project/doctible_pre_treatment/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I'm using brew to install ruby and rails using this setup guide

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

Help please, upgrading to Yosemite has totally messed with my dev environment

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this problem has to do with a recent update of XCode. After a XCode update you need to do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
2. Reinstall the Command Line Tools.

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. If `xcode-select --install` does not work try to start the `Install Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked for me:

`gem install libv8 -- --with-system-v8`

`gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'`

if that didn't work try to run:

`brew update`

and try again the first two steps.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue by changing the Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

was replaced by

```
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
```

Could you try this?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for Catalina

```
 brew install v8@3.15

 gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.19 -- --with-system-v8

 gem install therubyracer -- --with-v8-dir=/usr/local/opt/v8@3.15
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/fernandoaleman/868b64cd60ab2d51ab24e7bf384da1ca#gistcomment-3129128)